# How to add new Device in existing Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

Have just registered in iOS Dev program in this weekend.

I need to add a couple of devices to an existing Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. But when I push Edit button, I can change only Name and App ID. There is no option of lists of all devices. Please guide me

Thanks

!see image[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PksMb.png)

Comment: Have you added device before creating provisioning ?

Comment: I had added 2 device in device tab and then create adhoc profile but i want to add one more device in existing adhoc profile but there not show any devices list :(

Comment: It seems you are editing a wrong Provisioning Profile, as per you image it seems its not an `Adhoc profile`, so no device.

Comment: No dear, its correct Provisioning Profile

Comment: Same issue here! Created a new provision profile, can't add any devices when editing it. Though I can add some on my old (2-10 months ago generated) provisions. Weird. 30 devices added on account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer to the following section, in the documentation:**

[Editing Provisioning Profiles in Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW28)

**Additionally, see also:**

[Registering Individual Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW15)

[Creating Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW60)

Hope this helps.

Comment: exactly, but in my case there is no device lists shown :( :(

Comment: Strange. When you log into the developer program (https://developer.apple.com/ios) and navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", you don't see "Devices" section? What's your role? i.e. Admin, Technical, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not added any device on development program. First you need to register your devices (under the tab of Devices) then you may see option of devices[image: like this one]

Comment: I had already added 3 device in device tap and there are all shows in development program but not show device list in distribution program. see above image

Comment: hmmm I think you should contact to apple support team, because I am not facing this issue as shown in above image

Answer (score 0):

You need to add devices on the left pane on apple developer site.Then you move to the distribution/developement tab then follow the below step .
on provisioning profile -> select your ad hoc provisioning -> Edit -> devices -> select device.

You can now have your devices in the provisioning and successfully run in your device.
have a happy developing.

Comment: I had added 2 device in device tab and then create adhoc profile but i want to add one more device in existing adhoc profile but there not show any devices list :(